# Seguridad en mi conexion SQLServer y VB.NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, .net

mi pregunta consiste en consultar si mi conexion está garantizado a presuntos ataques o es vulnerable a aspectos que no logro identificar.

La estrucutura que manejo en mis proyectos es la siguiente:

> Clase conexion.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class conexion
    Protected con As New SqlConnection

    Protected Function conectar()
        Try
            con = New SqlConnection("Cadena de conexion")
            con.Open()
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Excepcion")
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

    Protected Function desconectar()
        Try
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                con.Close()
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Excepcion")
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

> Clase para mis funciones CRUD y demás operaciones.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class fCRUD
    Inherits conexion
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Public Function recuperaDatos(ByVal dts As vParametros) As DataTable
        Try
            conectar()

           cmd = New SqlCommand("nombreProcedimientoAlmacenado", con)
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parametro", dts.gparametro)
            If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery Then
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                da.Fill(dt)
                Return dt
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Return Nothing
        Finally
            desconectar()
        End Try
    End Function
End Class

...
```

Y ya en las vistas (frm)

Por dar un ejemplo:

```
Dim func As New fCRUD
dt = func.recuperaDatos(parametros)
```

Si alguien me ayude en encontrar alguna vulnerabilidad o verificar que es correcta la forma de manejar mis conexiones, estaría agradecido infinitamente

Comment: Para el ConnectionString puedes usar encriptado y desencriptado: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168240/encrypting-decrypting-a-string-in-c-sharp y los querys no deben realizarse dentro de la aplicación, trata de hacerlos mediante procedimientos almacenados ya que es más fácil de modificar luego de estar publicada tu aplicación.

Comment: Los queries no deberían estar en la base de datos, como dices es más fácil modificarlos ya estando en producción pero creo que si lo que le preocupa es la seguridad, la base de datos la debería mover sólo el DBA y no el programador, por lo que es correcto que los queries estén en la lógica, sólo recomiendo que no uses asteriscos en tus SELECT * y si usas los queries parametrizados como en tu ejemplo evitas la inyección.

Comment: Lo siento amigo no concuerdo contigo, trabaje en un banco donde hay DBA y Desarrolladores. Nosotros desarollamos los querys, el DBA los publica en la BD, trata de modificar un query dentro de una aplicación en puesta en producción sin tener que volver a publicar y sin parar el servicio. Esto es imposible, es por ello que los querys no deben estar dentro de la aplicación. No puedes modificar el código de aplicaciones que están en producción, solo para modificar un query.

Comment: @SdeSistemas lee el siguiente articulo te puede ayudar un poco sobre tus incógnitas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362975/c-sharp-sql-connection-string-best-practice

Comment: Si tienen que editar ya estando en producción sólo habla mal del sistema, no llevan un buen control de cambios ni calidad, saludos.

Comment: Entiendo los comentarios @shop350 es un punto importante a considerar y si he usado procedimientos almacenados (he actualizado mi pregunta).

Comment: Gracias @VictorPerdomo, echaré un vistazo tus recomendaciones.

Comment: Es recomendable que la cadena de conexión esté fuera de la compilación de la aplicación ya que si surge alguna eventualidad con el servidor, no tendrías que compilar nuevamente el programa por haberle cambiado la ruta. Esto te lleva a tener que guardar encriptada dicha cadena de conexión (puede ser en el regedit o en algún archivo sin extensión, etc.)
Podrías también reforar la seguridad del servidor SQL encriptando todas las vistas y los procedimientos almacenados.
Por lo demás lo veo bien.